# Laptop restarted by itself

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, shutdown

System info:

- MSI GS63 7RD (few months old)
- Windows 10 v1709
- At the time the laptop was connected to 4 external displays (2 of them displaylink)

I left my computer awake on the lock screen. It is supposed to go to sleep after 2 hours. I came back 3 hours later. The computer was in sleep mode, but had restarted by itself (and has an uptime of 2.5 hours).

I checked the Windows update history, and there have been no installed updates for the past week. I left the computer locked at 5:00 and came back at 8:00. System event viewer shows some strange/unexpected events in the meantime below. One odd thing to note is that when I woke the computer from sleep, it was already logged in.

My blurry picture of what happened: I lock the computer, half an hour later it reboots for no apperent reason, upon reboot automatically logs in somehow, instantly sleeps, and then is woken 2.5 hrs later by me.

**System event log:**

- 05:33 The kernel power manager has initiated a shutdown transition. Shutdown reason: Kernel API (plus many other shutdown events)
- 05:33:40 The operating system started at system time [5:34] (plus many other startup events)
- 05:33:50 the last shutdown's success status was true. The last boot's success status was true
- 05:34:05 The system is entereing sleep. Sleep Reason: Application API
- 05:34:06 The system has resumed from sleep
- [no events for the next 2.5 hrs]
- 08:07 The system has returned from a low power state. Wake Source: Power button